# Помогите с tkinter'ом, пожалуйста

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть основной модуль с главным окном и модуль с окном класса Toplevel. Вызывая последний как основной он отрабатывает штатно, вызывая же его по нажатию кнопки в главном окне что-то идет не так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так это выглядит при запуске модуля Notes_widget
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import tkinter as tk
from Calendar import show_calendar
from Notes_widget import show_notes_widget

class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_main()

        # Настройка фрейма на главном окне
    def init_main(self):
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(text='Выбрать дату', width=20, height=3, command=show_calendar)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(text='Ввести задачу', width=20, height=3, command=show_notes_widget)

        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn2.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создание главного окна
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Создание фрейма на главном окне
    app = MainMenu(root)
    app.pack()

    # Настройка параметров главного окна
    root.title('ИВРО')
    root.width = 180
    root.height = 110
    root.x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    root.y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.geometry(f'{root.width}x{root.height}+{int(root.x - root.width / 2)}+{int(root.y - root.height / 2)}')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    root.mainloop()
```

И побочный модуль

```
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Введите заметку")
        self.btn = tk.Button(text='Hello')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(bg="darkgreen", fg='white')
        self.text.pack()
        self.geometry('800x800')
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


def show_notes_widget():
    notes_widget=NotesWidget()
    notes_widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: *что-то идет не так*, Что именно?

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться как вставить скрины

Comment: вставте, я потом поправлю

Comment: Отдельно запущенный модуль Notes_widget выдает окно, куда можно писать текст и еще одно окно (что за окно вообще такое?). При вызове по нажатию кнопки окна для ввода текста нет, присутствует только главное окно с его наименованием. Мои подозрения падают на эти строки     def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self) побочного модуля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам не принципиальна работа с `tk.Toplevel`, то я могу предложить такое исправление для *Notes_widget.py*:

```
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Введите заметку")
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='Hello')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root, bg="darkgreen", fg='white')
        self.text.pack()
        self.root.geometry('800x800')
        self.root.grab_set()
        self.root.focus_set()

        self.root.mainloop()


def show_notes_widget():
    notes_widget=NotesWidget(tk.Tk())
```

**Проверил, работает как при вызове с кнопки, так и при запуске в качестве главного окна.**

---

**Дополнено:**

По факту, все, что я сделал - **указал при определении кнопки и текста параметр `self`**.

Теперь, при вызове из главного окна все работает как надо. И это `tk.Toplevel`

```
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Введите заметку")
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Hello')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(self, bg="darkgreen", fg='white')
        self.text.pack()
        self.geometry('800x800')
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


def show_notes_widget():
    notes_widget=NotesWidget()
    notes_widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо, за содействие. Собственно говоря от такого варианта я и пытаюсь убежать, так как есть нюанс, grab_set не работает и можно наспамить эти окна в произвольном количестве. Можно наверное скрывать вызывающее меню, а появившееся расположить поверх без права перемещать, но как по мне так это костыль. Проблема именно в корявом конструкторе, это видно по двум всплывающим окнам, одно принадлежит классу Toplevel (видно по title'y и geometry), а второе классу ТК (видно по наличию кнопки, Text'a и дефолтному title'y ТК). Завтра ещё поковыряю. Самостоятельный вызов модуля вообще не нужен

Comment: Можно же еще после перехода в другой модуль, основное окно убивать (`destroy()`), а потом возвращать, по нажатию какой-нибудь кнопки "Назад" из доп. модуля. Ну, или же просто ставить "выключенное положение" нажатой кнопке из главного модуля. Ну, как я понял, вам это тоже не подходит?

Comment: @ПавелРодин, дополнил ответ, посмотрите, может вас устроит результат :)

Comment: Присматривался к destroy(), тоже вариант, вечером после работы опробую с ещё парой пришедших в голову идей

Comment: @ПавелРодин, там на самом деле можно без `destroy()`, просто дописать `self`, в параметрах кнопки и текста. посмотрите в ответе, работает как надо вроде

Comment: Да, уже так сделал, все работает, спасибо.